# Magento2: Add Edit/Delete action link in separate Column in Admin Custom Grid using layout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I have created admin grid using layout. and i have added column generation code in app\code\Demo\Grid\view\adminhtml\layout\demo_grid_test_index.xml

i am able to use below code for edit row, but i want to show action column for edit and delete.
did anyone have implemented such action columns in Grid, implemented using layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Demo\Grid\Block\Adminhtml\Slide" name="ng_slide_grid">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="demo_grid_grid.grid" as="grid">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Demo\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\Collection</argument>
                        <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                        <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="demo_grid_grid.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                                <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                                    <item name="code" xsi:type="string">getCode</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="id">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="image">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slide</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">image</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">image</argument>
                                <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Demo\Grid\Block\Adminhtml\Thumbnail</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="position">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Position</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">position</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">position</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="status">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                                <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Demo\Grid\Model\Config\Status"/>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">status</argument>
                                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">status</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Manage Slides</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue

Comment: @SaravananDS: Yes i solved this, but with different way, i used block to create grid rather than XML, i found few restriction or can say didn't found any help to resolve this, i tried a lot, but nothing worked, then i changed the way of creating grid. if you need to know how i did, comment me.